# Writing a MySQL Query that involves 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to write an MySQL query, but I am having a difficult time writing it and it involves 3 tables!!!

```
table 1 - Invoice table - Has a client id, credit id, invoice id and commission subtotal
table 2 - Credits table - Has a client id, credit id and commission amount (same as commission subtotal)
table 3 - Agents table - Has a client id and agent id
```

I am trying to create a list of agents commission amount from credit table per credit id on invoice id.

I really hope that makes sense.

This what I have those far:

```
select cfi.commissionamount
        from invoice ii
        inner join clientagent cli
        on ii.client = cli.clientid
        inner join clientagent cl
        on ii.client = cl.clientid
        left outer join creditfee cfi
        on cfi.client = ii.client
        and (cfi.issuedate BETWEEN ii.startdate AND ii.enddate)
        where ii.invoiceid = cfi.invoiceid
        and cli.clientagentid = cl.clientagentid
```

But the only thing that gets returned is a bunch of random rows from my invoice table....any ideas on how to fix this?

Any help or step in the right direction would be a huge help.

Comment: It would be useful to see the table structures.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Any reason that your two joins on clientagent have identical conditions? There's no point in joining the same table twice if the join conditions are the same.

Comment: Is Invoiceid unique in the credit free table, or can multiple clients have the same one?

Comment: The invoice id is unique in the credit fee table

Comment: Expected output would be a list of agents (can be multiple) with a unique invoiceid and commission subtotal from credits fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for this, but you need to answer the questions above for us to help you more and provide an accurate table structure as you have spaces in your cell names.

```
SELECT cli.agentid, SUM(cfi.commissionamount)
    FROM invoice AS ii
        INNER JOIN clientagent AS cli
            ON ii.clientid = cli.clientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN creditfee AS cfi
            ON cfi.clientid = ii.clientid AND (cfi.issuedate BETWEEN ii.startdate AND ii.enddate)
        WHERE ii.invoiceid = cfi.invoiceid AND cli.clientagentid = cl.clientagentid
        GROUP BY ii.clientid
```